# Fixture acts like if it is unedited

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have basic `User` model, which has fixture in model test:

```
user1: {
name: somemail,
email: somemail@mail.ru,
encrypted_password: somepassword
}
```

The problem is, that when I wrote this fixture first time, I made a mistake, and named column `password` instead of `encrypted_password` (how it is named in Model).

When I first ran `rake test`, I got an error:

```
  1) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_shoud_create_user:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "password".



  2) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "password".
```

I figured out that I messed up writing fixture, changed `password` to `encrypted_password`, but each time I ran rake test I get **same errors** as if I edited nothing.

What may be reason of it and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the column named in db/schema.rb?

Comment: @BrentEicher t.string   "encrypted_password"

Comment: Would it help to restart Spring? `spring stop`, then running the tests again should boot Spring back up.

Comment: thanks, that worked) I'll accept if you provide answer